# Problems with touch events and Processingjs 1.4

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, processing

I'm getting errors with Processingjs on chrome 37 running on android. When I'm using Processing v1.4.3 or higher, at every touch the debug console returns this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: eventHandlers is not defined

I've tryed to use previous versions but I still got an error: the first touch isn't recognized by Processingjs and the debug console returns this error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.

After the first touch, everything starts going well.

I've googled but it seems that no one has encountered these particular errors. I get it even on an empty canvas with only size setting in the setup. How can I remove these error and make Processingjs able to recognize all touch events?

Comment: can you file this over on our issue tracker at http://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/issues please, with some minimal code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Of course. Visiting your link I've found that there's an issue already opened similar to mine, so I've just commented it: https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/issues/99